# How to set growup effect to play video inside that view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-animation

I want to create a application in iPad. like "Showyou" in iTunes

For that i need to set growup effect of the view when user touch the video thumnail image and hide with animation at its place when user touch outside the view like popover in ipad.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the ShowYou app but it seems like you need an animation to grow/shrink a view and possibly move it. If that's the case try this

```
// to make it grow in this case 1.5 and move it to a into position in this case 100, 100
[UIView animateWithDuration:_animationDuration
                 animations:^{
                     CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5f, 1.5f);
                     testView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 100.0f, 100.0f);
                 }
];


// make it go back
[UIView animateWithDuration:_animationDuration
                 animations:^{
                     someView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                 }
];
```

You might want to use animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: so that you can add code to do something after the animation is done.  Hopefully that's what you are looking for. :)